# What was the cause of the corruption of the forest in "Uprooted"?

Tags: uprooted

In Naomi Novik's *Uprooted* the enchanted forest near Agnieszka's village seems to be the story's antagonist - its trees trap and destroy people, even the wind blowing the mist from the forest can be lethal, contaminating the crops of the nearby village, causing the people who eat it to become insane and go on a murderous rampage.

Yet it seems that once the forest was just a regular, harmless one. What caused the change in the forest?

Comment: Well this is quite well described in the last part of book. Did you read it all?

Comment: @Mithoron i admit, towards the end i skipped a lot of pages :P can you pls summarise in a few sentences what corrupted the forest?

Comment: Not what, but who... You missed on the real villain :/ I think you should go back to reading.

Comment: Lots of people have read it (myself included), but the answer *is* right there in the book.

Comment: @Adamant well that's the case in most of our SFF questions,  the answer is usually in the books/films.

Answer (score 3):

#### The forest is made up of a tree-people who turned into trees to survive, and the corruption is caused by trapped humans’ pain and their Queen’s anger.

The forest of “heart-trees” used to be a race of tree-people that lived on the land. Their queen married a human king, who brought some of his people to the wedding.

> “By the time we reached the grove, the wedding was over. The Wood-queen and her king were standing on the green mound with their hands clasped, a chain of braided flowers wrapped over their arms. The wood-people were gathered around them, scattered loosely through the trees, watching and silent. There was a quiet in all of them, a deep inhuman stillness. The handful of men from the tower eyed them warily, and flinched from the rustling murmurs of the heart-trees. The young hard-faced man was standing just to one side of the couple, looking with a twist of distaste at the Wood-queen’s strange, long, gnarled fingers where they wrapped around the king’s hands.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

The queen of the tree-people believed that her marriage to the human king would forge an alliance with the humans that would be beneficial to both of them.  She thought their two peoples would be able to learn from each other, but the king’s people did not want to change.

> “When the sorcerer-king came with his people, my sister let them come into the valley. She thought they could teach us to remember. She thought we could be renewed, and teach them in turn; we could give each other life. But they were afraid. They wanted to live, they wanted to grow stronger, but they didn’t want to change. They learned the wrong things.” Years were slipping past us as she spoke, blurred like rain, grey and soft and piling on one another. And then it was summer again, a different summer a long time later, and the wood-people were coming back through the trees.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

Most of the king’s people did not actually want an alliance with the tree-people, and once the king was dead, they tried to kill all the tree-people instead, and imprisoned the queen of the tree-people.

> “She pointed away, down the river. “They are coming,” she said in her deep voice. “Look,” and I looked down at the river. Instead of the reflection of the sky I saw men coming in carved boats; they carried lanterns, burning torches, and great axes. A flag streamed at the head of the first boat, and in the prow stood the young man from the wedding-party, older and settled into his hard face; the one who’d bricked up the Wood-queen. He wore a crown of his own now.
>
> “They are coming,” Linaya said again. “They betrayed my sister, and imprisoned her where she could not grow. Now they are coming for us.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

To escape the humans trying to kill them, the tree-people chose to turn themselves into trees rather than be killed.

> “Some of them were stopping in open places, where the sun came down. They were eating the fruit, drinking the water. The mother chewed a piece of fruit and put it in her baby’s mouth, and gave it a sip from her cup.
> They were changing. Their feet were growing, toes stretching long, plunging into the earth. Their bodies were stretching, and they put their arms up towards the sun. Their clothing fell away into blown leaves, dry grass. The children changed quickest; they rose suddenly into great beautiful grey pillars, branches bursting wide and filling with white flowers, silver leaves coming out everywhere, as if all the life that might have been in them went rushing out in one furious gasp.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

When the queen of the tree-people escaped her imprisonment, she returned to find all her people turned into trees, and found two woodcutters (who do not seem to have suspected that the tree they were cutting down was anything more than any ordinary tree) cutting down one of them.

> “The Wood-queen gave a cry of horror that howled through the trees. The woodcutters halted, shocked, clutching their axes and looking around; then she was on them. She caught them up by the throats with her long-fingered hands and threw them away from her, into the river; they thrashed up coughing. She dropped to her knees beside the sagging tree. She pressed all her fingers over the oozing cut, as if she could close it up. But the tree was too wounded to save. It was already leaning deeply over the water. In an hour, in a day, it would come down.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

In an attempt to save the tree that the woodcutters had cut down, the Wood-queen merged one of the woodcutters into the injured tree. Doing this did save the tree, but the anguish of the trapped woodcutter also became part of the tree he was merged into, beginning the corruption.

> “The sapling sank away with the grove; the broken tree rose with us. The second woodcutter struggled up onto the bank, clinging to the shuddering ground. He swung his axe at the Wood-queen as she came towards him; it struck against her flesh and sprang away, ringing, jumping out of his hands. She paid no attention. Her face was blank and lost. She took hold of the woodcutter and carried him over to the wounded heart-tree. He struggled against her, uselessly, as she pushed him against the trunk, and vines sprouted from the ground to hold him in place.
>
> His body arched, horror in his face. The Wood-queen stepped back. His feet and ankles were bound against the chipped gap where the axes had bitten into the tree, and they were already changing, grafting onto the trunk, boots splitting open and falling away as his toes were stretched out into new roots. His struggling arms were stiffening into branches, the fingers melting into one another. His wide agonized eyes were disappearing beneath a skin of silver bark.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Uprooted (Chapter 31)*</sup></sub>

The pain of the human trapped within the tree sickened the tree as well, turning it monstrous.

> “If you will not come, you will be alone here,” she said. “Your sorrow and your fear will poison my roots.”
>
> I stood silent, afraid. I was beginning to understand: this was where the Wood’s corruption came from. The wood-people had changed willingly. They still lived, they dreamed long deep dreams, but it was closer to the life of trees and not the life of people. They weren’t awake and alive and trapped, humans locked behind bark who could never stop wanting to get out.
>
> But if I wouldn’t change, if I stayed human, alone and wretched, my misery would sicken her heart-tree, just like the monstrous ones outside the grove, even as my strength kept it alive.”

The anger the queen felt at her people’s fate, and the pain of the woodcutter (and then the other humans who were imprisoned in trees) poisoned the forest and fed into its corruption, eventually turning it into the lethal Wood hostile to humans seen at the time the story of “Uprooted” takes place.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wikipedia entry,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uprooted_(novel))  the heroine

> Agnieszka has a vision of the past where she learns that the Wood
>   Queen was part of a group of magical people who lived in the forest.
>   She married a human king however once he died his people turned on the
>   wood people causing them to choose to become trees in order to protect
>   themselves. After they failed to kill the Wood Queen she returned to
>   her people only to find them turned into trees and in a misguided
>   effort to protect them, began feeding human people to the trees.

Comment: This answer doesn’t truly explain the reason the forest became corrupted, though.